# How to fill an array with unique ids and date?

Tags: arrays, lodash, date-fns

I want to populate an object array with unique ids and an increment of Date.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    date: Mon Mar 07 2022, // date object
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    date: Tues Mar 08 2022, // date object
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    date: Wed Mar 09 2022, // date object
  },
  ...
];
```

I've tried the following:

```
import uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId';
import add from 'date-fns/add';

const startDate = Mon Mar 07 2022 // this is a date object

const time = new Array(7).fill({
      id: uniqueId()
      date: add(startDate, { days: 1 }),
    });
```

But this gives me the same id and the same date for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lodash's `_.times()` to create an array of, and use the generated `index` to create the `id`, and increment the date ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-with-date-fns-s13lb7?file=/src/index.js)):

```
const time = times(7, (index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  date: add(startDate, { days: index })
}));
```

Without lodash you can use `Array.from()` to create the array ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/array-from-with-date-fns-forked-bz5hg6?file=/src/index.js)):

```
const time = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  date: add(startDate, { days: index })
}));

console.log(time);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ori, that worked as expected